# How to create XCode archive without a clean build

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive

We have a fairly large code base that takes a long time to clean build.  Whenever we archive the build (Product->Archive) the archive process first cleans all, then builds.

This seems unnecessary and time-consuming, we would like to be able to create an archive without a clean build.  Incremental builds should be fine.

Does anybody know how to disable the "clean all" step during the XCode archive process?  Thank you so much, my searches on this have come up with nothing but advice on how to make a build faster (which is not useful advice for us).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

As I suspected would be the case this can be done from the command-line.  It took us a while to figure this out.  Here is an excerpt from our TeamCity build scripts.  Basically you generate a build (clean or incremental is your choice), then generate and .ipa from the build.  Here is one option (developer identity and provision profile ID removed of course):

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"

xcodebuild -project <PROJECT NAME>.xcodeproj -target <PROJECT NAME> -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CONTRIB_PATH=%system.agent.home.dir%/Contrib2 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: <DEV NAME> (ID)"  
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<PROFILE ID>

rm -rf Payload
mkdir Payload

cp -R build/Release-iphoneos/ Payload/

rm ~/<PROJECT NAME>.ipa
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v Payload/<PROJECT NAME>.app -o ~/<PROJECT NAME>.ipa --sign "iPhone Developer: <DEV NAME> (ID)" --embed ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/<PROFILE ID>.mobileprovision
```

Comment: Since `PackageApplication` is gone in Xcode 8.3, do you know if there is a new way to create  an .ipa without a clean build?

Comment: Regrettably I do not know, but if I learn how I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a continuous integration server, so that every commit can trigger a process that results in an archived build. . . (hopefully after running tests, etc first), as well as publishing API docs, et al.

It will still take the same amount of time, but since its running in the background after every checkin of code, and the latest release candidate will always be available - you probably won't notice.

Otherwise, you run into a headache where you have to do your development in Release mode instead of debug, etc - **its just not going to work**.

Here's an example of an (OSX) project that includes a build script that can be run by a continuous integration server. I used Bamboo, but if you want something free there's also eg Jenkins:

https://github.com/jasperblues

In the above project, each successful build (triggered whenever someone commits code) publishes API docs and test coverage reports back up to the github page. . . for an iOS project you could also have it do archiving.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. We do have a continuous integration server, but sometimes a developer is stuck making testflight build after testflight build and every line of code change results in 25 minutes of waiting for a recompile.

Answer (score -2):

Incremental builds are *not* fine for Archive. The point of the clean is because sometimes you can get issues in incremental builds that a clean fixes. That's an acceptable problem to have during development, but Archive is intended for distribution builds, and distribution builds should not have this risk at all.

Not to mention, your normal build process is building a Debug build, and Archive is going to build a Release build, so you're going to need to rebuild most of the app anyway (anything that changed since your last Release build).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would accept that clean builds are best for an app store submission just to be safe, but frequently we are in a state where a developer will want to push 30 builds to testflight per day. This results in 30 clean builds (because these are archives) at 25 minutes apiece is 30 x 25 = 1 billion years :(

Comment: Have you ever considered pushing fewer builds?

Comment: Haha. Of course. At the moment we are developing testflight integration features, so not at the moment. Most days this isn't the state of affairs.

Comment: @Ihavenocat: Well, my only other suggestion is to figure out why compile times are so long. 25 minutes is a pretty damn long compilation.

Comment: Massive project, absurd amount of code. We are moving towards faster builds but the details are tricky considering our project. I miss the days of iOS casual games when our builds were easily under 5 minutes clean.

Comment: @Ihavenocat: Are you using clang or GCC? Do you have too many dependencies between parts of your code? Replacing `#imports` with `@class` in headers, if you can, can reduce even clean compilation time (since the compiler will have less code to parse).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kevin.  We have a project to decrease compile times and it is going well, but honestly our code base is massive and we are reaching a limit of what we feel we can reasonably do.

Comment: another scenario when archiving without a clean build would be useful is when XCode gets mad and start complaining about wrong profiling files and similar issues. everytime you have to wait for a clean build to know if it is magically working again

Comment: "Don't do that" is sometimes a horrible answer; the question is specific about that. For example, I maintain a pretty big project that truly takes 50min to build, with pre-compiled headers and everything. And I have to wait for an hour when I change nothing in a project, just hit some new iTunes limitation like ITMS-90503. Spent whole day on 5 iterations trying to submit an app.

Comment: @VictorSergienko The error you quoted means that you do in fact have to rebuild your project, because you had it set to only build the active architecture and therefore did not produce the expected fat binary. If you meant to paste some other transient ITMS error, then in that case you don't have to rebuild at all, just resubmit.

Comment: In fact, not. I needed to remove a single-architecture requirement from a info.plist... and just had to recompile.